# What is the difference between std::transform and std::for_each?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl-algorithm

Both can be used to apply a function to a range of elements.

On a high level:

- `std::for_each` ignores the return value of the function, and
  guarantees order of execution.
- `std::transform` assigns the return value to the iterator, and does
  not guarantee the order of execution.

When do you prefer using the one versus the other? Are there any subtle caveats?

Comment: `transform` has an output range, `for_each` doesn't.

Comment: A lot of `<algorithm>` consists of functions that are very similar, just have a *slight* difference.

Comment: @o11c this is exactly what I'm looking for. There must be a good reason for the slight difference.

Comment: @bendervader The point is: `<algorithm>` is used a *lot*. Convenience is the biggest (if not only) motivating factor for that whole header.

Comment: Lots of algorithms that take a Callable have to work around `void` return values, have you tried assigning `void` to *anything*?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`std::transform` is the same as `map`. The idea is to apply a function to each element in between the two iterators and obtain a different container composed of elements resulting from the application of such a function. You may want to use it for, e.g., projecting an object's data member into a new container. In the following, `std::transform` is used to transform a container of `std::string`s in a container of `std::size_t`s.

```
std::vector<std::string> names = {"hi", "test", "foo"};
std::vector<std::size_t> name_sizes;

std::transform(names.begin(), names.end(), std::back_inserter(name_sizes), [](const std::string& name) { return name.size();});
```

On the other hand, you execute `std::for_each` for the sole side effects. In other words, `std::for_each` closely resembles a plain range-based `for` loop.

Back to the string example:

```
std::for_each(name_sizes.begin(), name_sizes.end(), [](std::size_t name_size) {
    std::cout << name_size << std::endl;
});
```

Indeed, starting from C++11 the same can be achieved with a terser notation using range-based `for` loops:

```
for (std::size_t name_size: name_sizes) {
    std::cout << name_size << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: to extend on this, in C++14 we can remove the type from the range based for loop to now be: for (name_size: name_sizes){ ... }

Comment: nice! last time I checked it was just a proposal. I generally use `for (auto&& x: xs)`, but that level of abstraction was not really crucial for the explanation.

Comment: @TrevorHickey I quickly checked again, and I cannot find any news apart the original proposal N3853. Are you sure about this?

Comment: I'm mistaken.  This is not a part of C++14, but it will be a part of C++17.  You can run it on Clang/GCC now given the right flag:  
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60d36ec0325242b7

Comment: Not exactly. `std::for_each` is not meant to have side effects, i.e. modifying the container by reference, as another user pointed out. It's not consistent with the principles, as the same user pointed out.

Comment: I don't agree with your definition of side effect (the "i.e." part). Printing out any information to the console is a typical example (if not "the" example) of side effect. This is in fact coherent to @bugshotgg's explanation you are probably mentioning.

Answer (score 26):

Your high level overview

> - `std::for_each` ignores the return value of the function and guarantees order of execution.
> - `std::transform` assigns the return value to the iterator, and does not guarantee the order of execution.

pretty much covers it.

Another way of looking at it (*to prefer one over the other*);

- Do the results (the return value) of the operation matter?
- Is the operation on each element a member method with no return value?
- Are there two input ranges?

One more thing to bear in mind (*subtle caveat*) is the change in the requirements of the operations of [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) before and after C++11 (from en.cppreference.com);

- Before C++11, they were required to "not have any side effects",
- After C++11, this changed to "must not invalidate any iterators, including the end iterators, or modify any elements of the ranges involved"

Basically these were to allow the undetermined order of execution.

*When do I use one over the other?*

If I want to manipulate each element in a range, then I use `for_each`. If I have to calculate something from each element, then I would use `transform`. **When using the `for_each` and `transform`, I normally pair them with a lambda.**

That said, I find my current usage of the traditional `for_each` being diminished somewhat since the advent of the range based `for` loops and lambdas in C++11 (`for (element : range)`). I find its syntax and implementation very natural (but your mileage here will vary) and a more intuitive fit for some use cases.

Comment: could you pls elaborate a bit on why "std::transform ... does not guarantee the order of execution"?

Comment: This is in contrast to the `for_each` algorithm, it is required to apply the function to each element in order. The requirements of the `transform` operations to not have any side affects means the order of execution wouldn't be observable, so not guaranteed. That all said, the implementations I've looked at all apply it in the expected order, first to last.

Answer (score 18):

Although the question has been answered, I believe that this example would clarify the difference further.

`for_each` belongs to **non-modifying STL operations**, meaning that these operations do not change elements of the collection or the collection itself. Therefore, the **value returned by for_each is always ignored and is not assigned to a collection element**. 
Nonetheless, it is still possible to modify elements of collection, for example when an element is passed to the f function using reference. One should avoid such behavior as it is not consistent with STL principles.

In contrast, `transform` function belongs to **modifying STL operations** and applies given predicates (unary_op or binary_op) to elements of the collection or collections and store results in another collection.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

void printer(int i) {
        cout << i << ", ";
}
int main() {
    int mynumbers[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    vector<int> v(mynumbers, mynumbers + 4);

    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), negate<int>());//no effect as returned value of UnaryFunction negate() is ignored.
    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), printer);      //guarantees order

    cout << endl;

    transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), negate<int>());//negates elements correctly
    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), printer);
    return 0;
}
```

which will print:

```cpp
1, 2, 3, 4, 
-1, -2, -3, -4,
```

Comment: Your emphasizing on the `modifiability` aspect is hocus-pocus. Because you admit that `for_each` can be made to modify something, although not idiomatic if doing so. In conclusion, both `for_each` and `transform` can indeed `modify` according to your own statements. And therefore, `modifiability` is not a determining characteristic to differentiate them. Rather than emphasizing `modifiability`, I would rather emphasize `order` because this is an absolute differentiator based on specification.

Comment: @eigenfield How is the aspect hocus-pocus. It is how it is defined and how it was intended to be used. Finding a workaround doesnt change this.

Answer (score 2):

Real example of using std::tranform is when you want to convert a string to uppercase, you can write code like this :

```
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(out), ::toupper);
```

if you will try to achieve same thing with std::for_each like :

```
std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), ::toupper);
```

It wont convert it into uppercase string

Comment: [Here's an example](https://godbolt.org/z/h1nxaj3Kn) of how to do it with `for_each`